# What is the best way to run background script in firefox Addon script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have to make a small modification on a legacy addon built in Addon SDK that's why I am not using webextension. I am trying to make a background script that should be running in the background as long as the addon is installed. I have an HTML panel and there is a script that is attached to it. But the panel's script runs only when the button is clicked. I tried to make another panel and attach the background script to it simply as:

```
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var backgroundPanel = panels.Panel({
    contentScriptFile: "./background.js"
});
```

But the `background.js` never runs. How to run a script on the background automatically as long as the addon is installed without the need to be triggered?

Comment: Did you try 'window.setInterval()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have already shown, commonly placed in a file called *index.js*, is *already* executed when the add-on is added to Firefox (i.e. upon add-on installation and when Firefox loads the add-on each time Firefox starts up) and will be executing until Firefox closes. It is **already** your background script.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run multiple files as background?

Comment: Yes, through multiple methods. The recommended method is: [Creating Reusable Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Creating_reusable_modules)